# representing large number in python

Tags: python

I am getting a large value as a string as follows

```
s='1234567'
d='12345678912'
```

I want to do arithmetic as `(100/d)*s`
To do this, I need to convert the strings to appropriate large values. What would be the way to represent them as a number?

Comment: Numbers in python can be as large as you want them to be. No need to use strings. Just do `int(number)` and you're done. Python 3 has great number features.

Comment: Check out the Decimal module

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I think `int` won't work with the example OP has given, it will output `0` in most cases.

Comment: @mu無 In python 3, it will work fine, but in 2 it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert them using [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float). Python takes care of creating appropriately large representation. You can read more about [Numerals here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric).

```
s='1234567'
d='12345678912'

(100/float(d))*float(s)
```

You could convert them using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), but as @GamesBrainiac pointed, that will work only in Python3; in Python2 it will most of the time give you 0 as result.

```
(100/int(d))*int(s)
```

Comment: @user2626431 It is working fine for me. What are your input values? Do they contain whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

If `s` and `d` are large e.g., thousands of digits then you could use [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) to find the fraction:

```
from fractions import Fraction

s = int('1234567')
d = int('12345678912')
result = Fraction(100, d) * s
print(result)
# -> 30864175/3086419728
```

`float` has finite precision; It won't work for very large/small numbers.